# How to animate a UITextView that is a subview?

Tags: iphone, animation, uiscrollview, uitextview

I am trying to animate a UITextView (myTextView) that is a subview inside a UIScrollView (scrollView).

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:myTextView cache:YES];
[scrollView addSubview:myTextView];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

myTextView appears without animation!

Comment: `addSubview:` doesn't animate anything by itself. How exactly do you want your text view to appear?

Comment: I want the textview to appear with the UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of animation do you want to do? If you want to fade in, for example, you have to do

```
[scrollView addSubview:myTextView];
myTextView.alpha = 0.0;
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:myTextView cache:YES];
myTextView.alpha = 1.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

You can change several properties (e.g.: frame, transform) to make animations.

Comment: The fade in works great, thank you :-)
But how can I have the textView appear with the UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.4shared.com/dir/-PGqZEXR/zoominzoomout.html just add this file with your project and call it through this functions

here im2 is UIVIEW and i paste image on it then passing this through view didload like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [self loadFlowersInView:im2];
     [self.view addSubview:im2];
}
```

now attach this function like this

```
- (void) loadFlowersInView: (UIView *) backdrop { 
      NSString *create_button = nil; // Add the flowers to random points on the screen
      for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) { 
           MagPicAppDelegate *appdelegate = (MagPicAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
           NSString *whichFlower = appdelegate.imageName;
           UIImage *stemp = [UIImage imageNamed:@"approve.png"];
           DragView *dragger = [[DragView alloc] initWithImage:stemp];
           dragger.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
           dragger.center = CGPointMake(160.0f, 140.0f);
           [im2 addSubview:dragger];
           [dragger release];
      }

      [self.view addSubview:im2]; 
      [im2 release];
}
```